# Creating a window with WinAPI in constructor of class?

Tags: c++, winapi, constructor

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html) on how to create a window with *WinAPI* in C++, and I wonder if I can create the window from a constructor of a class, instead of using the

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    ...
}
```

method, so that I can call the constructor of my custom class `Window` from the main class of the program, input the wanted size, title etc. and use it as a reference for my window, like the `JFrame` in java, so that I can then hide it, render stuff on it etc.

If this isn't possible, is there any other solution which can get it working in a similar way?

Comment: Yes, but where do I get the `hInstance`, `hPrevInstance`, `lpCmdLine` and `nCmdShow` variables from to pass into the function then?

Comment: You don't. gha.st's comment makes no sense. You don't call WinMain, it is the entry point(or one of the possible entry points) for your application, and it cannot be a member function of a class.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley *cough* paying attention helps; I deleted the comment which was beyond ridiculous when looked at in the light of day...

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 - I would like to add that you should not be attempting to create class wrappers for Windows API entities until you have the experience in non-object oriented Windows programming.   It's one of those things where you need to know how it all works before designing a wrapper.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay, I'll remember that when learning ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JFrame example tells me that you are searching for a way to create a Window by constructing a Window-Object.

`WinMain` does not create a Window it is just Windows' version of `main()`.

The Window is created by a call to `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()` somewhere else in your program.

The base-Winapi only offers this function (it is meant to be used from C), but there are the MFC Wrappers. E.g. `CWnd` represents a Window-Object ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xb05f0h.aspx))

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the, a bit stupid question... I'm verry new to C++ :)

Comment: It is a valuable question. Many people new to the Winapi at first think that there must be a Window-Object and later find out that it is just a struct; and maybe later use MFC (although they dont have to).

Comment: Where can I get the `HINSTANCE`s, the `LPSTR` and the `nCmdShow` `int` which is provided by the `WinMain` function, if I create the window somewhere else?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 Today HINSTANCE and HMODULE are the same, so you can use GetModule (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with an argument of NULL. And to get the command line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, what is the difference between the `CreateWindow()` and `CreateWindowEx()` functions, and `WNDCLASSEX` and `WNDCLASS`?

Comment: "Ex" is a general postfix in the Winapi meaning that it can do additional things. In general you can look it up in msdn. In this case CreateWindowEx takes the additional Ex-Style as first argument which can be combinations of these flags: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your entrypoint can never be a member function, but you can write object-oriented GUI code.  Just have `WinMain` create your main-window object, and let everything else happen from there.

Raymond Chen has a great [C++ version of a GUI scratch program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx), designed as a starting point for object-oriented Win32 GUI.

As you can see in his `WinMain`, creation of UI widgets is delegated to the `RootWindow` class.

```
int PASCAL
WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int nShowCmd)
{
 g_hinst = hinst;

 if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL))) {
  InitCommonControls();

  RootWindow *prw = RootWindow::Create();
  if (prw) {
   ShowWindow(prw->GetHWND(), nShowCmd);
   MSG msg;
   while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }
  }
  CoUninitialize();
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a question, what does the "pre-compiler directives" (right?) `#define STRICT`, `#define UNICODE` and `#define _UNICODE` mean?

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx